# Firestore (19.17.1) WebChannel Transport Error, Long Polling

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

### I am often receiving a 400 error with a firestore listener in React JS

Here is how I am initializing Firestore:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const fK = process.env.REACT_APP_FK;
const fDom = process.env.REACT_APP_FDOM;
const pId = process.env.REACT_APP_FPID;
const fSB = process.env.REACT_APP_FSB;
const fMSID = process.env.REACT_APP_FMSID;
const fId = process.env.REACT_APP_FID;
const fMID = process.env.REACT_APP_FMID;

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: fK,
    authDomain: fDom,
    projectId: pId,
    storageBucket: fSB,
    messagingSenderId: fMSID,
    appId: fId,
    measurementId: fMID
  };

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true,
});
```

I have also tried *experimentalForceLongPolling*, and disabling *useFetchStreams*. using `getFirestore()` to initialize firestore does not work either, I still get the same error.

#### Here is the error, stack trace minimally reduced:

```
GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=[Truncated...] 400
k.send @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:270
k.da @ xhrio.js:664
ec @ channelrequest.js:570
Fd @ channelrequest.js:525
k.Ia @ webchannelbase.js:1673
xb @ run.js:140
Promise.then (async)
ub @ run.js:58
sb @ run.js:33
yc @ webchannelbase.js:1617
mc @ webchannelbase.js:2090
k.La @ channelrequest.js:619
k.ib @ channelrequest.js:596
kb @ eventtarget.js:351
C @ eventtarget.js:481
td @ xhrio.js:878
k.fb @ xhrio.js:866
k.Ha @ xhrio.js:842
hd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:558
id @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:476
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:403
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:228
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Wa @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:355
Promise.then (async)
k.send @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:270
k.da @ xhrio.js:664
ec @ channelrequest.js:570
Fd @ channelrequest.js:525
k.Ia @ webchannelbase.js:1673
xb @ run.js:140
Promise.then (async)
ub @ run.js:58
sb @ run.js:33
yc @ webchannelbase.js:1617
mc @ webchannelbase.js:2090
k.La @ channelrequest.js:619
k.ib @ channelrequest.js:596
kb @ eventtarget.js:351
C @ eventtarget.js:481
td @ xhrio.js:878
k.fb @ xhrio.js:866
k.Ha @ xhrio.js:842
hd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:558
id @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:476
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:403
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:228
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:228
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:228
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:228
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Wa @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:355
Promise.then (async)
k.send @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:270
k.da @ xhrio.js:664
ec @ channelrequest.js:570
Fd @ channelrequest.js:525
k.Ia @ webchannelbase.js:1673
xb @ run.js:140
Promise.then (async)
ub @ run.js:58
sb @ run.js:33
yc @ webchannelbase.js:1617
kc @ webchannelbase.js:2331
lc @ channelrequest.js:941
k.La @ channelrequest.js:619
k.ib @ channelrequest.js:596
kb @ eventtarget.js:351
C @ eventtarget.js:481
td @ xhrio.js:878
k.fb @ xhrio.js:866
k.Ha @ xhrio.js:842
hd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:558
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:403
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Wa @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:355
Promise.then (async)
k.send @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:270
k.da @ xhrio.js:664
ec @ channelrequest.js:570
cc @ channelrequest.js:504
k.Ja @ webchannelbase.js:1331
xb @ run.js:140
Promise.then (async)
ub @ run.js:58
sb @ run.js:33
zc @ webchannelbase.js:1258
X.m @ webchannelbase.js:778
Hr @ index.esm2017.js:13053
send @ index.esm2017.js:12877
Bo @ index.esm2017.js:13392
zo @ index.esm2017.js:13554
xu @ index.esm2017.js:13905
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13940
$u @ index.esm2017.js:13939
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13472
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13500
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:17414
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:17447
Promise.then (async)
Hc @ index.esm2017.js:17447
enqueue @ index.esm2017.js:17414
enqueueAndForget @ index.esm2017.js:17392
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13500
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13472
so @ index.esm2017.js:12880
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13120
setTimeout (async)
wo @ index.esm2017.js:13115
jo @ index.esm2017.js:13518
Go @ index.esm2017.js:13471
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13461
Promise.then (async)
auth @ index.esm2017.js:13452
start @ index.esm2017.js:13357
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13482
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13258
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:14306
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:17414
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:17447
Promise.then (async)
Hc @ index.esm2017.js:17447
enqueue @ index.esm2017.js:17414
enqueueAndForget @ index.esm2017.js:17392
handleDelayElapsed @ index.esm2017.js:14306
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:14288
setTimeout (async)
start @ index.esm2017.js:14288
createAndSchedule @ index.esm2017.js:14282
enqueueAfterDelay @ index.esm2017.js:17487
Ro @ index.esm2017.js:13258
Oo @ index.esm2017.js:13481
start @ index.esm2017.js:13357
ku @ index.esm2017.js:13920
Bu @ index.esm2017.js:13947
close @ index.esm2017.js:13442
Qo @ index.esm2017.js:13491
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13475
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13500
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:17414
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:17447
Promise.then (async)
Hc @ index.esm2017.js:17447
enqueue @ index.esm2017.js:17414
enqueueAndForget @ index.esm2017.js:17392
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13500
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13475
io @ index.esm2017.js:12883
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13079
(anonymous) @ index.esm2017.js:13062
kb @ eventtarget.js:351
C @ eventtarget.js:481
Y.va @ webchannelbasetransport.js:428
R @ webchannelbase.js:2375
mc @ webchannelbase.js:2147
Q @ webchannelbase.js:522
k.La @ channelrequest.js:698
k.ib @ channelrequest.js:596
kb @ eventtarget.js:351
C @ eventtarget.js:481
td @ xhrio.js:878
k.fb @ xhrio.js:866
k.Ha @ xhrio.js:842
hd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:558
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:403
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Wa @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:355
Promise.then (async)
k.send @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:270
k.da @ xhrio.js:664
ec @ channelrequest.js:570
Fd @ channelrequest.js:525
k.Ia @ webchannelbase.js:1673
xb @ run.js:140
Promise.then (async)
ub @ run.js:58
sb @ run.js:33
yc @ webchannelbase.js:1617
mc @ webchannelbase.js:2090
k.La @ channelrequest.js:619
k.ib @ channelrequest.js:596
kb @ eventtarget.js:351
C @ eventtarget.js:481
td @ xhrio.js:878
k.fb @ xhrio.js:866
k.Ha @ xhrio.js:842
hd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:558
id @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:476
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:403
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:228
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Wa @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:355
Promise.then (async)
k.send @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:270
k.da @ xhrio.js:664
ec @ channelrequest.js:570
Fd @ channelrequest.js:525
k.Ia @ webchannelbase.js:1673
xb @ run.js:140
Promise.then (async)
ub @ run.js:58
sb @ run.js:33
yc @ webchannelbase.js:1617
mc @ webchannelbase.js:2090
k.La @ channelrequest.js:619
k.ib @ channelrequest.js:596
kb @ eventtarget.js:351
C @ eventtarget.js:481
td @ xhrio.js:878
k.fb @ xhrio.js:866
k.Ha @ xhrio.js:842
hd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:558
id @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:476
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:403
Promise.then (async)
jd @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:370
k.Ta @ fetchxmlhttpfactory.js:228
Promise.then (async)
etc...
```

#### React Devtools Warning

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.17.1): Connection WebChannel transport errored: 
Jd {type: 'c', target: X, g: X, defaultPrevented: false, status: 1}
defaultPrevented
: 
false
g
: 
X {s: false, o: undefined, i: Ua, P: X, I: null, …}
status
: 
1
target
: 
X {s: false, o: undefined, i: Ua, P: X, I: null, …}
type
: 
"c"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Wb
```

#### MRE

```
  const fetchUserData = useCallback(() => {
    if (!navigator.onLine) {
      navigate("/");
      return;
    }
    if (auth.currentUser) {
      const docRef = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid);
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
        docRef,
        (docSnap) => {
          if (docSnap.exists()) {
            const userData = docSnap.data();
            // Handle userData
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          handleLogout();
          console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
        }
      );
  
      // Cleanup function to detach listener
      return () => {
        unsubscribe();
      };
    } else {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [navigate, handleLogout]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      fetchUserData();
    } catch (error) {
      setInfo("User data not found");
      console.error(error);
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [fetchUserData, navigate]);
```

I have a feeling that it may have to do with my `useEffect()` and `useCallback()` hooks, but I am uncertain. The user data is working fine, changes in the user document are seen from the app, this error just seems unnecessary.

Using `setLogLevel('debug')` I have found the following error logs:

```
[2023-06-04T21:54:23.588Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.22.1): PersistentStream close with error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed
logger.ts:115 [2023-06-04T21:54:23.591Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.22.1): WebChannelConnection Creating RPC 'Listen' stream 0x86195108: https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel {"httpSessionIdParam":"gsessionid","initMessageHeaders":{"X-Goog-Api-Client":"gl-js/ fire/9.22.1","Content-Type":"text/plain","X-Firebase-GMPID":"1:845193017408:web:d13f2eab4cf84fbe2e47a5","Authorization":"Bearer |OMITTED|"},"messageUrlParams":{"database":"projects/|OMITTED|/databases/(default)"},"sendRawJson":true,"supportsCrossDomainXhr":true,"internalChannelParams":{"forwardChannelRequestTimeoutMs":600000},"forceLongPolling":false,"detectBufferingProxy":true,"xmlHttpFactory":{"l":null,"j":false},"encodeInitMessageHeaders":true}
```

This looks like a timeout error, but I think I am correctly unsubscribing to the listener. This may be an issue with the `useCallback()` hook nature.

Comment: I am having similar symptoms in a project which doesn't even use React in a substantial manner or anywhere near the Firebase layer, and have already tried `experimentalForceLongPolling` and repeated updates to my client library version (iirc 9.15.x to 10.5.0 to 10.7.0, spanning several explicit firestore fixes).  The most salient similarity between my setup and what the OP describes is that I, too, use a significant number of change listeners, although not via useCallback().  Guessing this is just normal passive turbulence, but I agree it feels needlessly alarming given data does go through.